# Cryptic message on org-html-publish-to-html

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I am trying to publish org files to html but I receive this error upon trying to publish my .org file:

```
org-export-dispatch: Wrong number of arguments: #[(&optional force) "
```

Then a bunch of weird symbols that won't paste... followed by

```
[wconfig force org-publish-use-timestamps-flag project current-window-configuration     ((setwindow-configuration wconfig)) org-publish-get-project-from-filename buffer-file-name up     error ...] 4 ("/usr/share/emacs/24.1/lisp/org/org-publish.elc" . 31315) "P"], 2
```

Here is the setup of the relevant portions of my .emacs file for the publishing:

```lisp
(require 'org-publish)
(setq org-publish-alist
  '(("org-html" 
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "org"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
 :table-of-contents: nil
 :auto-postamble nil
 )
("org-static"
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/files"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
 )
   ("org" :components ("org-html" "org-static"))
   )
  )
```

Any suggestions as to why this won't publish?

Answer (score 9):

I was having a conflict with my syntax because of some recent changes to the exporter. Here is my code, which is now fully functioning:

```lisp
(require 'ox-publish)
(require 'ox-html)

(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(("org-html" 
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "org"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
 :table-of-contents: nil
 :auto-postamble nil)
("org-static"
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)
   ("org" :components ("org-html" "org-static"))))
```